# vim autocommand event for write all buffers :wa

Tags: vim

I'm currently using the following mapping to, essentially copy over any files written in my dev env to my local server via executing a script. It works fine for individual files. However, I have a habit of doing :wa to save all buffers open:

```
au BufWritePost /path/to/dev/* silent !$HOME/bin/somescript.sh %:p
```

Any suggestions for how I could rewrite this to be a conditional like:

```
if one file
  exec script to copy just that file # like I already have
if :wa
  # here I'd probably exec a script to just copy recursively
```

**EDIT**

Possible solution per ZyX's solution:

```
au BufWritePost /Users/rlevin/programming/sugar/Mango/sidecar/* silent !$HOME/bin/sugarbuild.sh %:p

" If we do :wa<CR> we check if command type is ':' and if command itself was
" 'wa'. If so, we call the command WA which calls BuildSidecarIfInProject.
" This checks if we're actually within the project's directory
cnoreabbrev <expr> wa ((getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() is# 'wa')?('WA'):('wa'))
command! WA :call BuildSidecarIfInProject()
function! BuildSidecarIfInProject()
  if fnamemodify('.', ':p')[:44] is# '/Users/rlevin/programming/sugar/Mango/sidecar'
    exec ":!$HOME/bin/toffeebuild.sh"
  endif                                                                                                                                                                        
endfunction
```

Comment: We don’t check whether “the command itself is wa”. We check whether it is the only input present on the command-line so that it won’t expand things like `e wa` to `e WA`. You are unlikely to run into this issue, but it is still a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to determine number of files saved, but you can remap/abbreviate wa:

```
command WA # command that executes a script to just copy recursively
cnoreabbrev <expr> wa ((getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() is# 'wa')?('WA'):('wa'))
```

Comment: I understand your logic and this could be the solution. But when I try this, and define: command! WA :echo "Got called" .. I don't see anything. I've sourced vimrc, etc. Any advice as to how I could debug your command? Thanks

Comment: @Rob 1. Replace `echo` with `echom` and watch the output of `messages` after running `:wa` because there is a plenty of reasons why message may be not displayed. 2. If it did not help then answer how you run `wa`. This solution assumes you are typing `:wa<CR>`.

Comment: Perfect, yes the echom worked; and yes I'm doing :wa<cr>. Any way to modify your command to check that we're within a path e.g. /path/to/dev* .. this way it doesn't always trigger even when I'm not working on the project. I'll also experiment on my own ;)

Comment: You can add a condition ` && fnamemodify('.', ':p')[:11] is# '/path/to/dev'`, either after `getcmdline() is# 'wa'` or inside a `WA` command (I believe latter is better).

Comment: Again much thanks. Ok, I posted an EDIT using your advise, which is working for me but requires that I opened up vi from the project directory; so shortcoming is if I'm somewhere else and do :e /path/to/project/file .. it will use the original location I was in and not work. Idea?

Comment: @Rob Use current filename instead of current directory. Current file name is obtained using `@%`, but then you also need to add `&& empty(&buftype)`. I personally have setup an autocommand that switches current directory to project directory.

Answer (score 2):

[Some smart guy](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29) once said, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  If you really need on-the-fly backup/deployment to your server, why don't you just run the recursive version every time, or possibly bound to a hotkey?  I.e. don't treat the single-file case specially.  For example, `rsync` is pretty good at avoiding unnecessary copying.